# "Error" on Advanced Digitizing Window in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, qgis-2.12

I have the word "Error" that has appeared on my Advanced Digitizing Panel since upgrading to QGIS 2.12.0 Lyon. It doesn't appear to actually affect anything negatively... has anyone else seen this or know what might be causing it?

[image: Error on Panel]

Comment: When I open this in QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa, the message reads _"CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool"_. So it **might** be the same thing apart from the different message (and that no icons show up in QGIS 2.10.1).

Comment: I've having the same issue here after ugrading to 2.12.!

Comment: Is this still an issue for people in 2.16?

Comment: Error does not seem present in the 2.16 build

Comment: I can confirm the same error in 2.14 - "Error" appears at the top of the advanced digitising panel.  In 2.16 the message is "CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool". In both instances QGIS has been started with --noplugins.

Comment: However, once you start an edit session the tool works correctly.  See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15073